# How to use default_line_end in csvwriter?

Tags: android

Have integrated a jar file having jar from au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter, but the issue is how to create a new line to it....The CSVWriter object does not have a method for the new line....

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it is automated according to their docs (as long as you use the proper constructor).

It looks like there are two constructors that allow you to set the line termination:

```
CSVWriter(Writer writer, char separator, char quotechar, char escapechar, String lineEnd)
```

> Constructs CSVWriter with supplied separator, quote char, escape char
>   and line ending.

or

```
CSVWriter(Writer writer, char separator, char quotechar, String lineEnd)
```

> Constructs CSVWriter with supplied separator, quote char and line
>   ending.

So you would instantiate the class with:

```
CSVWriter(writer, separator, quotechar, escapechar, DEFAULT_LINE_END)
```

or

```
CSVWriter(writer, separator, quotechar, DEFAULT_LINE_END)
```

Comment: Thanks Barak, for helping out. I will give it a try and get back to you

Comment: Barak, what I ve done is this: writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() +"/companyvisit.csv", false), ',', '"', CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END); but it does not seem to make any difference..I still get all the values in one row in the .csv

Comment: Hmm, I looked in their code and it is supposed to be appending ther line end.  You could try calling it out specifically `writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() +"/companyvisit.csv", false), ',', '"', "\n");`

Comment: I tried that too.. I guess there is some other problem.....Have not used a split..

Comment: Which method are you using to write the file?

Comment: writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() +"/companyvisit.csv", false),',');   This is the part of code. Here arraylist refers to an array storing the string values
    int count = 0;    
    String[] string_value = array_collect2.toArray(new String[array_collect2.size()]);    
    //List l = Arrays.asList(string_value);
    writer.writeNext(string_value);
      // writer.writeAll(h);
    //writer.writeNext(CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
    
    writer.close();